# Spring Boot JPA @ColumnDefault being wrongly interpreted on PostgreSQL: ERROR: cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I am updating my `Transaction` table to have a new column with the default value in Spring boot JPA like this:

```
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnDefault("confirmed")
    public String status;
```

But if I inspect the generated SQL query, it looks like this:

```
alter table Transaction add column status varchar(255) default confirmed not null
```

The default value is being interpreted as a variable now, and I am getting this exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression
```

I am using PostgreSQL 12 and Spring Boot 2.2.1.RELEASE.
Anything wrong I am doing here?

Comment: You should probably be using an enum (and a database enum) instead. Your SQL is very clear; you just need to quote your value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Chrylis -on strike- said, you need to quote your value.  See the [Hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation-column-default-value) for an example of setting a default value for a String column.  Note how the default value is surrounded by double and single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You should surround confirm with single quotes like this:

```
@ColumnDefault("'confirmed'")
```

Comment: nothing happens. no default value is inserted

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to set default value to your column, preferred method is

```
    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(255) default 'John Snow'")
    private String name;
```

Another option is to initialize on declaration.

```
@Column(name="status")
private String status = "confirmed";
```

Comment: But i don't want to explicit define the datatype, I will be using different DBMS

Comment: I have edited my answer, but doing this way is in assumption that DB is accessed only from your Application