# Default Values for Fields of JPA Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

In one of my projects I have a class that I want to retrieve and populate from a database using JPA. The lookup is working and the object is getting created, but I'm running into trouble trying to set default values for some of the fields. Ideally, I would set the defaults in the database itself, but the database is part of a different application that I can't modify. My next thought was to set a default value on the field i.e.

```
@Column
String foo = "abc";
```

but those defaults get overridden when I do a lookup like:

```
 Customer actual = entityManager.find(Customer.class, customerNumber);
```

I also tried using the @ColumnDefault annotation from hibernate with no success. I could do it in the getter method, but that seems like a bad idea.

I'm fresh out of ideas at this point. Is there some other way to handle this, or is what I want to do simply impossible?

Comment: this url will guide you. https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-default-column-values

Answer (score 1):

How did you use @ColumnDefault?
It seems you didn't wrap your default string with ''.

For example:

```
@ColumnDefault("'My default value'")
```

And you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67060354/9391162) for more information. Plus you can check the [link](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-default-column-values) by @[vaibhavsahu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15079012/vaibhavsahu)

Comment: Strange, I really thought that would work but it didn't. If I evaluate the customer after the call to entityManager.find, it still shows a null value for the foo field.